# Have a question about texas holdm questions

Tags: texas-hold-em, reading-hands

if the table has Q9922 and there are three players playing.
P1= 10 6
p2= 10 8
p3= 6 5

who takes the pot..

Comment: Questions that can be very easily answered by doing a quick Internet search are not ideal for this site. Your questions (and therefore the answers) should provide more depth and add more value to the site.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, the board plays for everyone, that is, if each person separately took their hole cards and combined them with the board, then the best 5-card hand that each person could make is 2 pair (9's and 2's) with a queen kicker.

Therefore, the pot is split 3 ways.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification..if in hand of any player would have been A or K then that person would have won..

Comment: Correct, since they would have a better kicker.

Comment: In the beginning it's maybe hard to understand. If you for example have QQ and your opponent has 72   and board shows AAAAK   its still a split pot and nothing else ;) even though your hand is 10 times better than your oppponents one.